# Create skillProficiency fails with error 'ErrorAccessDeniedForRole'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create new skills for different users using the Microsoft Graph API, but it always ends in the following error response.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDeniedForRole",
    "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-10-07T07:29:49",
        "request-id": "81ff3a7b-907d-4b20-8de2-83b76448e8fa",
        "client-request-id": "cf5f9444-dac4-b005-040c-e4bd1c489dd7"
    }
}
```

}

That process was already documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-post-skills?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp

I am using the following properties. It does not matter if I am trying to create skills through Graph Explorer or an Application
Registration in Azure AD. Both should be supported regarding the documentation, but end in the same error.

**Permissions:**  User.ReadWrite.All (Application or delegated)
**Uri:** [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Bid) or upn}/profile/skills
**Method:** Post
**Body:**

```
{
  "categories": [
    "Professional"
  ],
  "allowedAudiences": "organization",
  "displayName": "API Design",
  "proficiency": "generalProfessional",
  "collaborationTags": [
    "ableToMentor"
  ]
}
```

I tried several combinations of bodies and permissions. None of them was working. It always ends in the error shown above.

GitHub Issue I have already created.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10205
But it seems not like the right location for such an issues.

Please let me know if you need any further information.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my repeated tests, I came to a conclusion: You can only create `skillProficiency` for yourself, not for other users.(Please note that I set the `proficiency` attribute to `elementary`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. 
Creating new skills for myself worked for me.
That kind of solves a part of my problem, but I am totally fine with it.